# Galois group solvable but $f$ not solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I know from a theorem that:

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $f(x)\in F[x]$. Then $f(x)$ is solvable by radicals if and only if the Galois group of $f(x)$ is solvable.

But what if the field was not characteristic $0$?

I see the result that if $F = F_p(t)$ then this theorem is completely false. Where the Galois group is solvable but $f$ is not solvable where $f = x^p - x - t$ but why is this true?

I believe I can see why the galois group is solvable because the galois group is cyclic and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_p}$, but I cannot fully grasp why $f$ is not solvable. I tried do this by contradiction but got no result.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Ok, I now think my deleted comment did make sense. To rephrase: what is required is to show that there is no element $g(t)\in F$ such that $F[X]/(X^p - g(t)) = F[X]/(X^p-X-t)$.

Comment: So denote $F[X]/(X^p-g(t)) = F(\alpha)$ and assume this field contains an element $y = h(\alpha)$ such that $y^p - y -  t = 0$. Then $y = y^p - t = h(\alpha)^p - t = h(\alpha^p) - t \in F$.

Comment: Alright, how do I continue on with this? I cannot see how this shows that $f$ is not solvable by radicals.

Comment: Oh well if you agree with the above then it means that $F[X]/(X^p-X-t)$ cannot be obtained by adding a $p$-th root. But since it is an extension of degree $p$ your only chance of obtaining it by adding roots of equations of the type "$x^n - a$", i.e. solving the equation, is doing it in one step and adding a $p$th root of some element. But that doenst work because of the above...

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $f$ is solvable by radicals. Then we should have $$F\subset F(\alpha)\subset K\subset \overline{F}$$ where $K=F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_m)$ and $\alpha_1^{n_1}\in F, \alpha_i^{n_i}\in F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{i-1})$.

First, we may assume $p\nmid n_i$ unless $p = n_i$. For if $n_i = pr, r>1$, then we can first adjoin a r-th root and then a p-th root.

Secondly, if $p\nmid n_i, p\nmid \{F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{i-1},\alpha_i):F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{i-1})\}$. If $p = n_i$, then $X^p-\alpha_i^p$ is irreducible provided that $\alpha_i\notin F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{i-1})$ and $X^p-\alpha_i^p = (X-\alpha_i)^p$. Thus $1 = \{F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{i-1},\alpha_i):F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{i-1})\}$.

Therefore, $\{K:F\}=\prod_{i=1}^{m}\{F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{i-1},\alpha_i):F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{i-1})\}$ is not divisible by $p$. But we have $p =|G(E\ /\ F)|=\{E:F\}\mid \{K:F\}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: E is the splitting field of f over F.

Comment: If $p\nmid n_i$, why do we have $p \nmid [F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_i): F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{i-1})]$? If I'm not missing something this is non-trivial; for example this would be could be false more generally (consider $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)/\mathbb Q$, say, with $n_i = 3$)